# Find conditional expectation of $\int_1^2W_t^2dt$ with respect to $F_1$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

$$\mathbb{E}(\int_1^2W_t^2dt|F_1)=\int_1^2\mathbb{E}((W_t-W_1+W_1)^2|F_1)dt=\int_1^2\mathbb{E}((W_t-W_1)^2|F_1)dt+\int_1^2 2\mathbb{E}((W_t-W_1)W_1|F_1)dt+\int_1^2 \mathbb{E}(W_1^2|F_1)dt=\int_1^2(t-1)dt+2 \cdot\int_1^2 W_1\cdot 0 dt+\int_1^2 W_1^2dt=\frac{1}{2}+\int_1^2 W_1^2dt$$

Is this the correct anwser?

Comment: Ive got another question - those integrating limits aren't random yes? (1 and 2). What would happen if I took 0 and 4 instead?

Comment: Well, one can calculate $$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_a^b W_t^2 \,dt \mid F_1 \right)$$ for any $a \leq b$ using a very similar argumentation. Hint: If $a=0$ and $b=4$ write $$\mathbb{E}\left(\int_0^4 W_t^2 \, dt \mid F_1  \right) = \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^1 W_t^2 \, dt \mid F_1 \right) + \mathbb{E} \left( \int_1^4 W_t^2 \, dt \mid F_1 \right).$$

Comment: Yes, but where exactly we used the fact that limits of integration are "independent" of $F_1$?

Comment: What do you mean by "independent"? The limits of integration are simply real numbers....

Comment: I mean lower limit of integration is equal to index of $F$ in filtration, i.e. $E(\int_1^2 W_tdt | F_1)$

Comment: I mean if we changed $\int_1^2$ to $\int_0^5$ it wouldnt change the whole procedure, just numbers? So why you suggest sepearting that expected value into 2 parts?

Comment: We used it in the proof e.g. to conclude $$\mathbb{E}((W_t-W_1)^2 \mid F_1) = \mathbb{E}((W_t-W_1)^2).$$ If we consider the integral $$\int_0^4 W_t^2 \, dt$$ then this equality does *not* hold true for all $t \in [0,4]$.

Comment: ohhh right, im stupid. sorry and thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Given $\mathscr{F}_1$, $\beta_ t = W_{t + 1 } - W_1$ is a standard Brownian Motion independent of $W_1$. So, for $t \geq 1$,
$$
\mathbf{E}[ W_t^2 | \mathscr{F}_1 ] = \mathbf{E}[ (\beta_{t-1} + W_1 )^2 | \mathscr{F}_1 ] = t-1 + W_1^2.
$$
So that, 
$$
\mathbf{E}\left[ \int_1^2 W_r^2 dr \big | \mathscr{F}_1 \right] = 1/2 + W_1^2.
$$

Comment: So my first answer is incorrect?? How did u get $tW_1$

Comment: -1. The first displayed identity never holds ($t=0$? Wrong. $t=1$? Wrong again...). The second displayed identity holds only when $t=0$.

Comment: i made some typos, what about now.

Comment: Yes, now you are basically reproducing the argument in the question and this argument is correct.